# Calculating average shortest path from Graphviz file

Tags: graph, graphviz

I am using Graphviz to visualize some relationships as a graph. I also need to calculate the average shortest path and the average clustering coefficient for this graph. I figured there might be some existing tool out there that could do this for me, but I've looked all over and have come up blank. Is there something in Graphviz itself, or another compatible tool, that can do this analysis for me?

Below is an example of the type of file (in their `dot` language) I have and am looking to analyze.

```
graph G {
  a -- b;
  b -- d;
  c -- d;
  b -- l;
}
```

Comment: `gvpr` should do what you want. Steep learning curve ahead...  --  Part of the graphviz package, already installed.

Comment: @vaettchen I'm holding out hope for something already written, not something with a steep learning curve. I would imagine that such things already exist since this would be a pretty common analysis of graphs. If nothing pops up, then I guess I know where to go - thanks for the `gvpr` recommendation!

Answer (score 0):

After many hours of looking and asking around, I was eventually directed to https://github.com/gephi/gephi. It can read a DOT file, and then calculate a number of statistics (as well as doing a bunch of other cool things)!